# Excel 2010 VB Script error 1004 - Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable Class

Tags: excel, vba

I have read a heap of questions regarding this run-time error 1004 but none that I can find to fit, so your help is much needed.

I have recorded a macro in Excel 2010 which beginns with filtering a PivotTable. It is to remove 4 value fields but always get stuck with run-time error 1004 on the one named 'Sum of Application Ratio' (within asterixes in code below).

I find it very strange the earlier 2 ones works just fine and then changing the order of 'Sum of Applicaiton Ratio' with 'Count of Container Number', the 'Count of Container number' works just fine as well though not 'Sum of Application Ratio'. The codes seems exactly the same for me.

When doing it manually without the macro it works just fine to remove.

What can be the problem? Any and all help most appreciated.

```
    Range("B22").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(" PIO Billed Y "). _
    Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(" PIO Billed N "). _
    Orientation = xlHidden

**ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Application Ratio"). _
    Orientation = xlHidden**

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Count of Container Number"). _
    Orientation = xlHidden
```

Comment: Have you changed the name of the field in the pivot table from "Sum of Application Ratio"? Not the field in the original table but over typed the name that appears in the pivot display itself?

Comment: What does the code look like if you record yourself doing this manually?

Comment: @GavinP - Yes, have tried changing the name of the field to 'test', short and without spaces, but still the same.

Comment: @Jeeped - The cost looks exactly the same. This code is recorded doing it manually. Both as a full code, as well as recording stand-alone just this part, it remains the exact same.

Comment: I'm at a loss then, that code should work. Can you take a screenshot of the pivot table and post it? At the point you would run the macro.

Comment: I can't find any way to attached files/screenshots here :( Is it possible?